# Continuous view in Preview

Tags: mac

Is there a way to set Preview to `continuous view' by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select "View->PDF Display->Single Page Continuous" it should stay that way for all PDF you view until you change it.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!  I have been right clicking and choosing continuous for a year now!  (No idea why it does not save that preference, bad design).  THis is the most useful answer ever!